# Export stylized hair from blender to ue5 workflow

Tags: export, workflow, hair, unreal-engine

Good day. I can't find information about exporting stylized hair for anime character from blender to ue5. I want to know how to export it and how to animate it in unreal. I know that I can export particle hair as alembic file and simulate physics in ue5, but in case of stylized hairs we have separated nurbs and shouldn't fully simulate it (like in overwatch). So I'm looking for workflow or, at least, pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add bones and rig the hair nurbs in Blender. Here's a relatively popular video in Blender on how to achieve that. Because you're using Unreal physics, you don't have to do the wiggle / jiggle physics of the video past the 0:51 timemark

NSFW as it uses a nude model - [Blender 2.82 : Hair Rigging, Physics, & Animation (In 2 Minutes!!!)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTdRGZA4TXA)

Make sure you parent the hair to the head bone so it follows the head. And be sure the weight painting is done right. I recommend do a few strands at first to test it out. You can always go back when you're comfortable with the workflow

Export as FBX. Make sure the hair bone look similar to this in Unreal. [image]

Click on 'Character' drop down near the top left on the viewer window. [image: You can find out how to display the bones in Unreal here] Then, you have to set up an AnimBP for the physics. There is AnimDynamics and KawaiiPhysics, both are free and there are some video tutorials. Both are used for clothes physics too. Here's a link to a tutorial for KawaiiPhysics. You may have to adjust the settings to get the physics you need. [Kawaii Physics in Unreal Engine 5 | Easy Bone Physics in UE5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JJhgsJh14c)

Comment: Cool! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!